# Adding properties to angular's FormController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

When adding form validation to a bootstrap project I find myself writing this pattern a lot:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div class="form-group"
        ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.email.$invalid && (myForm.$submitted || myForm.email.$touched) }">
        <label>Email*</label>
        <input type="email"
            class="form-control"
            name="email"
            ng-model="checkout.info.customer_email"
            required />

        <div class="help-block"
            ng-show="myForm.email.$invalid && (myForm.$submitted || myForm.email.$touched)">
            <div ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">This field is required.</div>
            <div ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">This email address is not properly formatted.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I was trying to figure out if there was an easy way to add a new property to the form controller's element, something like:

```
 myForm.email.$showError = myForm.email.$invalid && (myForm.$submitted || myForm.email.$touched
```

I could just create a function for this, but it doesn't quite feel like the right solution to have to write `showError(myForm, myForm.email)` but maybe thats a lot easier after looking at the source code for FormController

Comment: You could write a directive that takes the form as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I can't specifically recreate your code here, but the best way to see the angular form object is to attach it to a parent scope object.

In a parent controller define this:

```
            $scope.myFormScope = {};
            $scope.myFormScope.showError = function() {
                if(!!$scope.myFormScope.myForm) {
                    return $scope.myFormScope.myForm.email.$invalid &&
                        ($scope.myFormScope.myForm.$submitted || $scope.myFormScope.myForm.email.$touched);
                }
            }
```

And then here's what the markup would look like

```
         <form name="myFormScope.myForm">
            <div class="form-group"
                ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myFormScope.showError() }">
                <label>Email*</label>
                <input type="email"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="email"
                    ng-model="checkout.info.customer_email"
                    required />

                <div class="help-block" ng-show="myFormScope.showError()">
                    <div ng-show="myFormScope.myForm.email.$error.required">This field is required.</div>
                    <div ng-show="myFormScope.myForm.email.$error.email">This email address is not properly formatted.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
```